# What's the difference between で and と

Tags: particle-と, particle-で

で and と particle can be used to mean "and" in english. For example:

彼女はお金持ち**で**きれい

Aさん**と**Bさんはいません

In the sentences above, both と and で means "and", but they are not interchangeable. When would one use と and で to imply "and" in english?

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese you can chain independent statements together by conjugating the statement in the middle into the te-form and just sticking them together. This is what's happening in your first sentence, with で being the te-form of だ. There are two complete statements there: お金持ちだ and きれい. Those both work as sentences by themselves.

The と particle is used for grouping nouns together. (It has other uses as well that aren't relevant here.)

A noun by itself isn't a complete sentence, nor can it be conjugated, so the first method doesn't work on the second sentence. And likewise, since the first sentence isn't combining nouns, と doesn't work there.

Comment: It isn't a verb

Comment: I searched a bit and some people explain it as chaining nouns with で, but to me viewing it as chaining independent sentences together is more intuitive.