# で and と when used to chain nouns

Tags: word-choice

Both で and と can be used to mean "and" when used with nouns. For example:

兄は一番大切で愛しい人 - brother is the most precious and dearest person

兄は一番大切と愛しい人 - brother is the most precious and dearest person

Both seems ok to me. Question is, which one and under what circumstances should I use each of them?

Comment: Looks rather like this question of yours. If the answer there doesn't help you then please explain in more detail what your problem is. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75055/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%81%a8/75057#75057

Comment: @user3856370 Edited

Comment: But now you've changed your two nouns into a na-adjective and an i-adjective. Does that give you any hints? See if you can find a real sentence that uses で with two actual nouns.

Comment: @user3856370 一人暮らしで単純の生活がいい. In this case both で and と sounds ok to me

Comment: ^ 1人暮らしで単純**な**生活, right? (not 単純の生活, cos 単純 is a なadjective.) 1人暮らしで[質素]{しっそ}/[簡素]{かんそ}な生活 would be more natural, though. 1人暮らし**と**単純/質素/簡素な生活 is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is wrong as Japanese. と is and for nouns. You can say 兄と弟は一番大切で優しい人

Comment: Thanks. What if I changed it to 兄は一番大切と親切人, will this be grammatically correct? Or should I really always use と when chaining nouns?

Comment: It's also wrong. Don't use と for adjectives. If you want to emphasize 兄 has two characteristics, you can say 兄は一番大切な人であり、優しい人だ